# Problems with captions

Tags: captions

I am experiencing an annoying problem with the caption of this figure:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fix-cm,relsize}

\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage{amsmath,kbordermatrix,amsthm,amssymb,subfigure,mathrsfs,rotating,array,graphicx,url,booktabs, multirow,eurosym,color}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage{boldline}

\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}

\usepackage{makecell}

\setdescription{style=multiline,topsep=10pt,leftmargin=2.1cm,font=\normalfont}

\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\usepackage[a4paper, includeheadfoot, left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,headheight=0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[pdftex,pdfstartview=FitBH,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\kbldelim}{(}% Left delimiter

\renewcommand{\kbrdelim}{)}% Right delimiter

    \begin{figure}[!b]
      \centering
      \parbox{5cm}{
        \begin{eqnarray*}
              \kbordermatrix{
                & t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_4 & t_5 \\
                t_1 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 2 \\
                t_2 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 3 \\
                t_3 & 3 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
                t_4 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
                t_5 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 0
              }
        \end{eqnarray*}
        }
        \quad
        \begin{minipage}{5cm}
            \centering
               \begin{tabular}{|c|ccc|}
                 \hline
                 Taxon & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\small{Sequence}} \\
                 \hline
                 $t_1$ & A     & A     & A \\%& \ldots\\
                 $t_2$ & A     & C     & C \\%& \ldots\\
                 $t_3$ & C     & G     & C \\%& \ldots\\
                 $t_4$ & C     & C     & G \\%& \ldots\\
                 $t_5$ & G     & A     & G \\%& \ldots\\
                 \hline
               \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}
        \caption{The Balanced Minimum Evolution Model (BMEM) is an alternative example of a phylogenetic estimation model that can be described as an optimization problem. The BMEM arises from the distance methods and, as for the MPM, it represents a phylogeny of a given set $\Gamma$ of taxa as an UBT having $\Gamma$ as leaf-set. The BMEM assumes the existence of a measure of dissimilarity (or \emph{distance}) $d_{ij}$ for each pair of distinct taxa $i,j\in\Gamma$. When the observed heritable traits are molecular sequences, such a measure can be computed by using, e.g., one of the nucleotide substitution models described in \citep{Daniele1, FelsenBook, HKY, Lanave, JC, Kimura,  Rodri, Waddell, Beyer,Kidd,Fitch03, Galtier01, Huelsen05, Lopez,Kidd}. As an example, if we would just use the Hamming distance to measure the dissimilarity among the molecular sequences shown in Figure~\protect\ref{Figure02}, we would obtain the symmetric distance matrix shown on the left of this figure. Based on this information, the BMEM states that the phylogeny of a given set $\Gamma$ of taxa can be computed by solving the following combinatorial optimization problem:
        \[
          \protect\min_{T\in \mathcal{T} } \; \displaystyle \sum_{\substack{i,j\in\Gamma\\i\neq j}} \frac{d_{ij}}{2^{\tau_{ij}}}
        \]
        where $\mathcal{T}$ represents the set of the $(2n-5)!!$ possible phylogenies of $\Gamma$ \citep{FelsenBook,Daniele10} and the \emph{path-length} (or \emph{topological distance}) $\tau_{ij}$ represents the number of edges belonging to the (unique) path from taxon $i$ to taxon $j$ in a phylogeny $T\in\mathcal{T}$ \citep{Pauplin,GascuelBook,Daniele11}. The optimal solution to this optimization problem when considering the above distance matrix is shown on the right of this figure.}\label{Figure03}
    \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

specifically, latex writes that there are the following errors:

> ```
> /Users/darkstar/Dropbox/Ricerca/Progetti/2017/2017 - 01 - ERC/A - Latex sources/ERCB2.tex:125: Argument of \caption@ydblarg has an extra
> }. [...ix is shown on the right of this figure.}]
> /Users/darkstar/Dropbox/Ricerca/Progetti/2017/2017 - 01 - ERC/A - Latex sources/ERCB2.tex:125: Paragraph ended before \caption@ydblarg
> was complete. [...ix is shown on the right of this figure.}]
> /Users/darkstar/Dropbox/Ricerca/Progetti/2017/2017 - 01 - ERC/A - Latex sources/ERCB2.tex:125: Missing $ inserted. [...ix is shown on
> the right of this figure.}]
> /Users/darkstar/Dropbox/Ricerca/Progetti/2017/2017 - 01 - ERC/A - Latex sources/ERCB2.tex:125: Missing $ inserted. [...ix is shown on
> the right of this figure.}]
> ```

However, all $ and } are correct! Where the problem is?

Comment: IMHO, you're grossly abusing the `\caption` macro. Captions work best when they're short and snappy. A half-page long block with embedded equations is not short and snappy.

Comment: also why use `eqnarray` here `eqnaarray` is deprecated even when it makes sense but there is just a single expression here with no alignment any `eqnarray` should have at least two rows and two `&` in each row. (and most should be replaced by `align`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please always post a full document that reproduces the error but in the standard classes `\caption` is set in horizontal mode to measure its width, which will make display math constricts such as `\[` fail.

The easiest way to disable that is to use the `caption` package with

```
singlelinecheck=false
```

This runs without error

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fix-cm,relsize}

\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage{amsmath,kbordermatrix,amsthm,amssymb,subfigure,mathrsfs,rotating,array,graphicx,url,booktabs, multirow,eurosym,color}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage{boldline}

\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}

\usepackage{makecell}

\setdescription{style=multiline,topsep=10pt,leftmargin=2.1cm,font=\normalfont}

\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\usepackage[a4paper, includeheadfoot, left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,headheight=0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[pdftex,pdfstartview=FitBH,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\kbldelim}{(}% Left delimiter

\renewcommand{\kbrdelim}{)}% Right delimiter

    \begin{figure}[!b]
      \centering
      \parbox{5cm}{
        \[
              \kbordermatrix{
                & t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_4 & t_5 \\
                t_1 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 2 \\
                t_2 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 3 \\
                t_3 & 3 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
                t_4 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
                t_5 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 0
              }
        \]
        }
        \quad
        \begin{minipage}{5cm}
            \centering
               \begin{tabular}{|c|ccc|}
                 \hline
                 Taxon & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\small{Sequence}} \\
                 \hline
                 $t_1$ & A     & A     & A \\%& \ldots\\
                 $t_2$ & A     & C     & C \\%& \ldots\\
                 $t_3$ & C     & G     & C \\%& \ldots\\
                 $t_4$ & C     & C     & G \\%& \ldots\\
                 $t_5$ & G     & A     & G \\%& \ldots\\
                 \hline
               \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}
        \caption[The Balanced Minimum Evolution Model]{The Balanced Minimum Evolution Model (BMEM) is an alternative example of a phylogenetic estimation model that can be described as an optimization problem. The BMEM arises from the distance methods and, as for the MPM, it represents a phylogeny of a given set $\Gamma$ of taxa as an UBT having $\Gamma$ as leaf-set. The BMEM assumes the existence of a measure of dissimilarity (or \emph{distance}) $d_{ij}$ for each pair of distinct taxa $i,j\in\Gamma$. When the observed heritable traits are molecular sequences, such a measure can be computed by using, e.g., one of the nucleotide substitution models described in \citep{Daniele1, FelsenBook, HKY, Lanave, JC, Kimura,  Rodri, Waddell, Beyer,Kidd,Fitch03, Galtier01, Huelsen05, Lopez,Kidd}. As an example, if we would just use the Hamming distance to measure the dissimilarity among the molecular sequences shown in Figure~\protect\ref{Figure02}, we would obtain the symmetric distance matrix shown on the left of this figure. Based on this information, the BMEM states that the phylogeny of a given set $\Gamma$ of taxa can be computed by solving the following combinatorial optimization problem:
        \[
          \min_{T\in \mathcal{T} } \;  \sum_{\substack{i,j\in\Gamma\\i\neq j}} \frac{d_{ij}}{2^{\tau_{ij}}}
        \]
        where $\mathcal{T}$ represents the set of the $(2n-5)!!$ possible phylogenies of $\Gamma$ \citep{FelsenBook,Daniele10} and the \emph{path-length} (or \emph{topological distance}) $\tau_{ij}$ represents the number of edges belonging to the (unique) path from taxon $i$ to taxon $j$ in a phylogeny $T\in\mathcal{T}$ \citep{Pauplin,GascuelBook,Daniele11}. The optimal solution to this optimization problem when considering the above distance matrix is shown on the right of this figure.}\label{Figure03}
    \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear David, thanks for the comment. Adding the line that you suggest, reduces the errors from 4 to 2. Unfortunately, still two errors persist, namely:

Argument of \caption@ydblarg has an extra }. [...ix is shown on the right of this figure.}]

Paragraph ended before \caption@ydblarg was complete. [...ix is shown on the right of this figure.}]

Comment: @DanCat fix your input example so that it produces any errors that you want help with, it's hard to debug by eye.  add `\documentclass...\end{document}` and anything else needed to reproduce the error

Comment: @DanCat do you _really_ want display math in the list of tables??? perhaps you are looking for `\caption[something reasonable]{long caption with \[ display\]}`

Comment: I need to display in the caption of the figure an equation. Trying to replace eqnarray with align does not change much. Unfortunately, I cannot move this part of the text elsewhere.

Comment: @DanCat it's just a single line, neither `eqnarray` or `align` should ever be used for a single line display. Just use `\[..\]`

Comment: @DanCat see update

Answer (score 0):

I can see no justification for including a multi-line display, including a displayed equation, in the argument of `\caption`. A short caption, say,

```
\caption{Balanced Minimum Evolution Model (BMEM)}
```

is almost much more helpful to your reader. The remainder of the material can be typeset as an ordinary legend. Simplifying the caption in this manner also permits getting rid of the two `\protect` statements and automatically gets rid of the error message you've been encountering.

Separately, don't use `eqnarray*`. A simple `\[ ...\]` contstruct suffices admirably.

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{graphicx,natbib,amsmath,kbordermatrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!b]
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\[
      \kbordermatrix{
        & t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_4 & t_5 \\
        t_1 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 2 \\
        t_2 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 3 \\
        t_3 & 3 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
        t_4 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
        t_5 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 0
      }
\]
\end{minipage}
\quad
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Fig03-SolutionBME}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Balanced Minimum Evolution Model (BMEM)} \label{Figure03}

\bigskip
The Balanced Minimum Evolution Model (BMEM) is an alternative example of a phylogenetic estimation model that can be described as an optimization problem. The BMEM arises from the distance methods and, as for the MPM, it represents a phylogeny of a given set~$\Gamma$ of taxa as an UBT having $\Gamma$ as leaf-set. The BMEM assumes the existence of a measure of dissimilarity (or \emph{distance}) $d_{ij}$ for each pair of distinct taxa~$i,j\in\Gamma$. When the observed heritable traits are molecular sequences, such a measure can be computed by using, e.g., one of the nucleotide substitution models described in \citep{Daniele1, FelsenBook, HKY, Lanave, JC, Kimura,  Rodri, Waddell, Beyer, Kidd, Fitch03, Galtier01, Huelsen05, Lopez, Kidd}. As an example, if we would just use the Hamming distance to measure the dissimilarity among the molecular sequences shown in Figure~\ref{Figure02}, we would obtain the symmetric distance matrix shown on the left of this figure. Based on this information, the BMEM states that the phylogeny of a given set~$\Gamma$ of taxa can be computed by solving the following combinatorial optimization problem:
\[
    \min_{T\in\mathcal{T}} 
    \sum_{\substack{i,j\in\Gamma \\ i\neq j}}
    \frac{d_{ij}}{2^{\tau_{ij}}}
\]
where $\mathcal{T}$ represents the set of the $(2n-5)!!$ possible phylogenies of~$\Gamma$ \citep{FelsenBook,Daniele10} and the \emph{path-length} (or \emph{topological distance}) $\tau_{ij}$ represents the number of edges belonging to the (unique) path from taxon~$i$ to taxon~$j$ in a phylogeny $T\in\mathcal{T}$ \citep{Pauplin, GascuelBook, Daniele11}. The optimal solution to this optimization problem when considering the above distance matrix is shown on the right of this figure.
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```